# PackageManager queryIntentActivities() returns empty list for deeplinks

Tags: android

We are building a native app that displays data which is provided by our clients via a web-based frontend. These data can contain url in `https` schema. Inside the app these urls should be clickable and open the url inside a browser, if one is istalled. Therefore we would like to check if an app is installed which can handle the intent, and if not display an error message.

The intent looks like this

```
Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=https://wa.me/... }
```

See below the function to check if an app exists for handling the intent

```kotlin
private fun hasAppToHandleIntent(context: Context, intent: Intent): Boolean {
    val packageManager = context.packageManager
    val apps = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_ALL)
    } else {
        packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0)
    }

    return apps.size != 0
}
```

As we are targeting android version >= 11 we need to handle the package visibility inside the `AndroidManifest` and added the following query

```xml
<queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="https" />
    </intent>
</queries>
```

This approach worked nicely until one of our clients put in a url which in the end leads to a deeplink into `WhatsApp`. It had the following format `https://wa.me/123456`. This url yields different results for the `hasAppToHandleIntent()` function on different devices.
On a Google Pixel 5 (running Android 12 ) and an emulator (running Android 10) the `queryIntentActivities()` function returns a list with installed browsers to handle the intent. On a Samsung Galaxy S20 however `queryIntentActivities()` returns an empty list, even though multiple browsers and WhatsApp app are installed.

What are we missing here? Why does `queryIntentActivities()` return an empty list?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the url with format `https://wa.me/123456` is, in some cases and devices, automatically treated as a deeplink into `WhatsApp` and NOT handled as a normal url. I did not find any documentation or information as to why this happens, so if anybody could provide additional infos I would very much appreciate it.

Following approaches would be possible:

1. Add a `query` for `WhatsApp` inside the `AndroidManifest`

```xml
<queries>
    <package android:name="com.whatsapp" />
    <package android:name="com.whatsapp.w4b" />
</queries>
```

As there could also be other deeplinks which could lead to the same problem. Adding all of them was no option for us

2. Declare that your app needs to query all installed apps, not just the ones declared by your `queries`. This approach was not tested but should work. See https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility/declaring#all-apps for further information. As stated there this way is not recommended and we did not use this approach either.
3. Our workaround approach first checks if `queryIntentActivities()` returns an empty list. If so we check if an app exists which can handle a normal https url.

```
private fun hasAppToHandleIntent(context: Context, intent: Intent): Boolean {
    val packageManager = context.packageManager
    val apps = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_ALL)
    } else {
        packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0)
    }
    
    if (apps.size == 0 && intent.dataString?.startsWith("http") == true) {
        val uri = Uri.parse("https://www.test.com")
        val urlIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).apply { data = uri }
        return if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            packageManager.queryIntentActivities(urlIntent, PackageManager.MATCH_ALL).size != 0
        } else {
            packageManager.queryIntentActivities(urlIntent, 0).size != 0
        }
    }

    return apps.size != 0
}
```